# How to handle uninstallation of my app correctly GCM wise

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I heard google blocks servers who keeps trying to send notifications to reg ids that are invalid, is this true? and if it is, whats the definition of an invalid reg id? and also In case reg ids are saved in a server, how do i know if a reg id is of a running app or when its safe to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any mention of such blocking in the GCM docs, but it's a good practice not to send messages to invalid/obsolete Registration IDs.

You should parse the response you get from Google when sending a GCM message. If you get "InvalidRegistration" or "NotRegistered" in the error field, you can delete the Registration ID from your DB.

Comment: and what if i send a set of reg ids at once?

Comment: @OfekRon You get a response for each of them. For example, if the 6th element in the response JSON has a NotRegistered error, that means the 6th Registration ID that was sent in your request should be removed from the DB.